# Swift Variable Number of Subviews in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory

I have a UITableView which displays custom cells. Each cell contains a scroll view, an image view, and a couple of text labels. This has all been setup in the storyboard. I set various properties of the text labels and image view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Straightforward thus far.

Now, I need to add a variable number of images to the scrollview in each cell. Currently, I update the content size of the scroll view and call `cell.contentView.addSubview` to add these images in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Unfortunately, this appears to cause a memory leak.

If I scroll up and down on the table view many times, it becomes very glitchy and slow. I suspect the subviews I add to the cell are not being deallocated. Each time 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' is called, I try removing all subviews of the cell, but this does not appear to solve the problem.

Where should I be adding subviews to the cell's scrollview so that they are deallocated each time the cell is reused?

Here is a section of my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsFeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsFeedCell
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Get the profile picture dimensions
    self.profPicWidthHeight = getProfilePictureDimensions(cell)

    // Reset all views in the friends subview
    for view in cell.friends.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // Get all info to display in cell
    cell.eventTitle.text = self.eventNames[indexPath.section]
    cell.time.text = self.eventTimes[indexPath.section]
    cell.entityPicture.image = self.eventImages[indexPath.section]
    cell.entityName.text = self.eventSponserNames[indexPath.section]

    // If this user has joined this event, add his/her image to the array
    if (self.eventsUserJoined[indexPath.section]) {
        self.eventUserImages[indexPath.section].append(self.meImage)
    }

    // Set the scroll view content size
    cell.friends.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(self.eventUserImages[indexPath.section].count + 2) * (self.profPicHorizontalOffset + self.profPicWidthHeight), cell.friends.frame.height)

    // Add profile images
    var i: CGFloat = 1
    for profPic in self.eventUserImages[indexPath.section] {
        cell.friends.addSubview(layoutProfilePicture(i, picture: profPic!, squareDimension: self.profPicWidthHeight))
        i++
    }
```

Any help you can provide is much appreciated!

Comment: `self.eventUserImages[indexPath.section].append(self.meImage)`  infinitely grows the array.

Comment: @rintaro Thanks! Eliminating this code solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use image caching to overcome the slowness. Your cells are redrawn every time they will appear on screen. If you don't use inMemory caching for the images, it will cause slowness. Take a look at SDWebImage and use it for setting the images.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

example use:

let url = NSURL(string: "http://my-images-url.com")

self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, completed: block)

Comment: I don't understand. If a have a fixed number of images in each cell and I lay them out in storyboard, the table does not become glitchy. Even if I have 20 images in each cell. It's only when I call `cell.contentView.addSubview` within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that the table becomes slow. Also I've pre-loaded all images in `viewDidLoad` and everything works fine in the beginning

Comment: do you fetch images remotely or do you have them locally stored?

Comment: I fetch images remotely, then store all of them locally. This same problem persists even if I only have one image in the entire table view and I scroll enough times

Comment: if you fetch them remotely everytime you draw the cell, without caching, it will be slow. So as I suggested, look into some swift friendly imageCaching libraries for this matter.

Comment: I only fetch the images once, in `viewDidLoad`. Each time I draw the cell, I access a local copy of the necessary images. It doesn't appear as though this lookup is the problem, though. The first ~30 time I scroll up and down the table view it works perfectly.